# Empty user-defined move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, move-constructor

The following code snippet which I was writing to understand move CTOR behaviour is giving me hard time to understand it's output:

```
#include <iostream>

class Temp
{
  public:

    Temp(){
      std::cout << "Temp DEFAULT CTOR called" << std::endl;
      mp_Val = nullptr;
    }

    Temp(int inp) { 
      std::cout << "Temp CTOR called" << std::endl;
      mp_Val = new int(inp); 
    }

    Temp(const Temp& inp) {
      std::cout << "Temp COPY CTOR called" << std::endl;
      mp_Val = new int(*inp.mp_Val); 
    }

    Temp& operator= (const Temp& inp) {
      std::cout << "Temp ASSIGNMENT OPER called" << std::endl;
      mp_Val = new int(*inp.mp_Val);

      return *this;
    }

    int* mp_Val;
};

class B
{
  public:

    B(){
      std::cout << "Class B DEFAULT CTOR" << std::endl; 
      mp_Val = nullptr;
    }
    B(int inp) { 
      std::cout << "Class B CTOR" << std::endl; 
      mp_Val = new Temp(inp);
    }

    B(const B& in) { 
      std::cout << "Class B COPY CTOR" << std::endl; 
      mp_Val = in.mp_Val;
    }

     B(B&& in){ 
      std::cout << "Class B MOVE CTOR" << std::endl; //Doubt: 1
    }

    Temp *mp_Val;
};

int main() {
  B obj1(200);
  B obj2 = std::move(obj1);
  auto temp = obj1.mp_Val;
  std::cout << "Obj1 B::Temp address: " << obj1.mp_Val << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Obj2 B::Temp address: " << obj2.mp_Val << std::endl; //Doubt: 2

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Class B CTOR
Temp CTOR called
Class B MOVE CTOR
Obj1 B::Temp address: 0xd48030
Obj2 B::Temp address: 0x400880
```

**GCC version: 4.6.3**

My question is about the line marked as Doubt 2. Should not the address be printed as 0? As per my understanding, as I have defined an empty move CTOR (marked as Doubt 1) in `class B`, it should call the default CTOR of class `Temp` (which it's not calling as evident from the logs) to initialise its member variable `mp_Val` of type `Temp`.

There is obviously something that I am missing.

Comment: After doing the move on obj1, obj1 is dead.  Yet your code continues to use it.

Comment: @Eljay That's not how move constructors work in C++.

Comment: @Eljay After moving `obj1` is in exactly the same state as before, since the move ctor does not modify its argument any way.

Comment: @Eljay obj1 is not yet dead, as I have not done anything in the move CTOR.

Comment: _"is should call the default CTOR of class `Temp`"_ No, it shouldn't, since `mp_val` is a pointer. It would if `mp_val` was a member variable of type `Temp`.

Comment: `obj2.mp_Val` was never initialized in the MOVE CONSTRUCTOR, so it contains a garbage value.

Comment: @Eljay that I have done on purpose to experiment. the actual code inside the move CTOR would be: 

B(B&& in): mp_Val(in.mp_Val) {  
      std::cout << "Class B MOVE CTOR" << std::endl;
      in.mp_Val = nullptr;
    }

Comment: @Upayan • since you did that intentionally, then do you understand the output?  Because garbage output would be what you ought to expect if you have uninitialized variables.

Comment: @Eljay I presumed it will call the default CTOR of the class Temp (as an initialiser list is missing in the move CTOR) and will init the value to 0. But, I missed the point that its a *Temp and not Temp, so it will not call the default Temp class CTOR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As per my understanding, as I have defined an empty move CTOR (marked as Doubt 1) in `class B`, it should call the default CTOR of class `Temp` (which it's not calling as evident from the logs) to initialise its member variable `mp_Val` of type `Temp`.

Your member variable isn't of type `Temp`, it's of type `Temp *`. You're right that the lack of an initialiser means that that member will be default-constructed, and for type `Temp` that would involve calling the default constructor. However, for pointer types, default construction leaves the object uninitialised.